How to achieve deterministic results with math/rand in Go tests without passing a random number generator?
I am writing Go tests and need deterministic results from functions that use the math/rand package. However, I don't want to pass a random number generator (RNG) explicitly to these functions, as this would require changes in multiple functions and tests.
In previous versions of Go, I could achieve this by calling rand.Seed with a constant number in my tests. But as of Go 1.20, using rand.Seed in this way is deprecated. The official documentation suggests using rand.New(rand.NewSource(seed)) for a local RNG, but this would require passing the RNG around, which I want to avoid.
How can I achieve deterministic results in my tests without passing the RNG explicitly, given the deprecation of rand.Seed? Is there an alternative approach that maintains the convenience of seeding for tests?
I tried using rand.New(rand.NewSource(42)) (without passing the RNG) instead of rand.Seed(42), but this doesn't yield detrministic results.

If you don't want to pass the prng as an argument, store it as a package-level variable (that's all the math/rand package generator is anyway)

With multi-threading you will have that situation more and more. There are situations where you want repeatable random numbers. And making a random number generator threadsafe can be expensive. You might consider switching to generator objects anyway.

You cannot.  This isn't a failure of the language or the tools, but a built in problem with your question at a conceptual level.  You cannot have a function that is Random and also Deterministic in the same way you cannot have a ball that is entirely red and also entirely blue.  Those are mutually exclusive concepts.  The fact that you used to be able to do it was a failure of the language previously, which they corrected.
So, while I completely understand why you want to do what you're asking, at a conceptual level it is impossible and Go is correct for handling it the way it does.  The idiomatic way to handle this is unfortunately to go through the hassle of passing a mock RNG around to all of your tests and rewriting the code to accept it.  As a consolation prize, doing this does make your code less fragile to future changes.
